# combining multiple grep searches and making my script more efficient

Tags: bash, grep, counter

I have a file called Type1.txt, that looks like this:

```
$ cat Type1.txt
ID.580.G3C0
TTTTTTTTTTT
ID.580.G3C8
ATTATATC-AAA
ID.580.GXC16
ATTATTTC-ACG-TTTTTCCTA
ID.694.G9C3
ATTATATC-ACG-AAATCCTA
ID.694.G9C3
etc...
```

I want to write a bash script to count the instances of each ID and export it into another file that provides a summary, something like this:

```
ID.580 = 3
ID.694 = 1
etc...
```

So far the script is messy and unusable.

For the above I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for Count in `grep -c "ID.580" Type1.txt; do
    echo $Count=ID.580
done > Result.txt  #Allows to count only for that single ID.
```

I have over a thousand ID.XXX, making this code unusable since it's not plausible to add individual ID.XXX for each search. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I've tried to clean your question up, but you may need to do some additional work to clarify your intent.

Comment: I'm a big fan of bash scripting--I use it all the time, and occasionally do some pretty complicated things.  However, this is something I'd do in Perl.  It would be utterly trivial in this case, and the logic would be straightforward.  The amount of Perl you'd need for this kind of task would be easy to learn from readily available examples.  And if you're going to be working with genetic data in text files a lot, getting used to Perl could come in handy later for rearranging data into different formats needed by different tools.  It was for me.

Comment: Thank you both! I was thinking of jumping into Python instead of Perl, suggestions?

Comment: @user1698774 if you must learn a programming language to solve this problem, i would suggest Java ;-) or if that's too boring, Haskell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shell

The code below uses the standard UNIX utilities, and does not assume that the second part of the ID is exactly 3 characters, but will find `ID.1.123123123` and `ID.1234.123123` and properly only take the first dot-delimited part. As it is

```
grep '^ID\.[0-9]' Type1.txt | cut -d . -f 1-2 | sort \
    | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2" = "$1 }'
```

- `grep` filters only lines beginning with `ID.` followed by 1 digit (at least)
- `cut` uses `.` as the field delimiter, and only outputting fields 1 and 2, thus removing
  everything after and including the second `.` on the line.
- `sort` sorts the lines for uniq to work
- `uniq` prints each line from its input prefixed with a count
- `awk` part reverses these fields and prints them separated with `=`.

If the first part of the ID can contain letters too, change the end of regular expression to `[0-9]` to `[0-9A-Z]`. for example

The pipeline outputs

```
ID.580 = 3
ID.694 = 2
```

### Python

As the Python is popular among biologists, you might want to hone your python skills instead:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('Type1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ID.'):
            top_id = '.'.join(line.split('.', 2)[:2])
            counter[top_id] += 1

for top_id, count in sorted(counter.items()):
    print("%s = %d" % (top_id, count))
```

The results are exactly identical.

Comment: if you are making such minor improvements to existing answers, you could always just edit one of them, or at least give credit. (besides, yours is the only undownvoted answer, so why hold back! ;-)

Comment: There is only limited number of command line tools available and any idiomatic solution would use `[ef]?grep`, `awk`, `sort` and `uniq` in exactly this order. All others solutions had problems however, so how to choose the one to fix?

Comment: Also my python code is more efficient in the case there are many ID lines as it does not need sorting

Comment: i understand not fixing, but it is nice to add a phrase "on the lines of the answers below" or something like that. no sweat, no big deal. (the python code came after the downvote; i was going to request Haskell too ;p )

Answer (score 0):

`grep '^ID.[0-9][0-9][0-9]' input_file | cut -c1-6 | sort | uniq -c`

works?

Comment: Your solution doesn't match the output format described by the OP.

Comment: asker says "something like this" for output, and clearly states that the problem is efficiency "I have over a thousand ID.XXXX, making this code unusable", but if you must be petulant and compare this logically correct solution with your rather permissive grep, which will give zero confidence for a large file, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Given your particular corpus and grouping strategy, there's more than one way to get the results you need. Here are two alternative solutions, one in awk, and one in Ruby.

### GNU awk

One way is to use GNU awk to perform the following steps:

1. match just the ID lines
2. split matching input lines into fields
3. select and print the fields you need
4. sort the lines in the filtered result
5. count the adjacent duplicates
6. perform any specialized formatting on the result

For example:

```
$ awk '/^ID/ {split($0, a, "."); print a[1] "." a[2]}' /tmp/foo |
    sort | uniq --count | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
ID.580 = 3
ID.694 = 2
```

With the corpus you provided in your question, this takes an average of 8 ms on my system. A larger corpus will take longer, of course, but unless you have a really huge data set this should be fast enough for most purposes.

### Ruby

Ruby offers what I consider a more elegant solution, but is in fact slower. The idea here is to store the relevant portion of your IDs as hash keys, and increment a counter each time you encounter a given ID. For example, consider this Ruby one-liner:

```
$ ruby -ne 'BEGIN { id = Hash.new(0) }
            id[$&] += 1 if /\AID\.\d+/
            END { id.each_pair do |k,v| puts "#{k} = #{v}" end }' /tmp/foo
ID.580 = 3
ID.694 = 2
```

This solution takes around 45 ms to process the same corpus, so I wouldn't recommend it over the awk pipeline just for transforming output. The main advantage to doing it this way is that you have an actual data structure (e.g. a [Hash object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html)) that you could manipulate in a more full-featured program.

Comment: the grep is rather permissive. also the asker wants to only look at the first two fields of id.

Comment: @user1698774 I've refactored the answer to better address your output format, and to give you some additional ideas of the procedural steps you might take to solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @randomstring The anchoring isn't necessary because "ID" shouldn't occur in a nucleic acid sequence, but it may allow the regex engine to fail faster on a significantly larger corpus; I decided to add it as a (potentially premature) optimization. As for grouping by ID, that's been addressed, too. Good luck!

Comment: good fixes. re anchoring ID, consider the line from posted input: "ID.580.GXC16" -- if "GX" can occur, so could "ID". it might not make a difference since there should be an "ID" ahead of it, but still with software it is good to add on some robustness. PS: I am curious why you chose `awk` rather than `grep ... | cut ...`? I'm sure there is a good reason, so just curious here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is awk one liner:

```
$ awk -F. '$1=="ID"{a[$2,$3]++}END{for (i in a) {split(i,ind,SUBSEP); r[ind[1]]++}for (i in r)  print "ID."i" = "r[i]}' file
ID.694 = 1
ID.580 = 3
```

And here is a pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=. read -r pre id code rest 
do
    [[ $pre == ID ]] || continue
    [[ ${a[$id]} =~ \."$code"\. ]] || {
        a[$id]="${a[$id]}.$code."
        ((count[$id]++));
    }
done < file
for i in "${!count[@]}"
do
    echo "ID.$i = ${count[$i]}"
done

$ ./script.sh 
ID.580 = 3
ID.694 = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

awk might work too...

```
awk '/ID.580/{x++}END{print x}' test.txt
```

You can put this in a for loop

```
for i in ID.580 ID.694
do
  awk '/'$i'/{x++}END{print x}' test.txt
done
```